# Lead sharing rule

Tags: configuration, sharing-rule

Lead - users at the same role level need access to each others Leads

I have users at the same level in the role hierarchy that need to read/write each others Leads. 
How do I set this up in the sharing settings for the lead object? 
Sharing settings have worked well for people sharing across various role levels....but this scenario not working for me.

I just set up a sharing rule that says all Leads owned by Role 1 are shared with Role 1
But it is not working.

Comment: _How do I set this up in the sharing settings for the Case object?_ It is confusing. Can you clarify why case object is mentioned here when you want to setup setting for Lead object?

Comment: Question is closed.
Thanks for the reply Adrian.

Comment: @Aditya No, you never [accepted an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234)...

Answer (score 1):

I think you would need to setup couple of rules to accomplish this:

[image: Lead Sharing Rules]

Best approach would be to create separate groups for each level and then create sharing rule for them. Like This:

[image: By Public groups]

Comment: Now it showing user's each others records.
But now problem is I have lead visualforce page. If I login user1 then it is not able no see records of user2 on visualforce page and viceversa.

Comment: If records are visible on salesforce UI then it should be visible on your custom vf page as well. Now it seems a completely new problem and  you should post it as a separate question, if problem persists.